# Não consigo baixar plugins pelo painel

Tags: php, wordpress

Olá, estou com um erro no meu wordpress não consigo instalar plugins diretamente pelo painel ai tava instalando pelo diretorio de plugins mesmo, dai ontem quando fui instalar um plugin chamado jetpack me veio esse erro:

  "register_http_request_failed"

será que alguem poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: alguém responde, por favor preciso de uma resposta urgente.

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser que bibliotecas estejam ausentes em seu host. Para saber qual biblioteca falta, o plugin já vem com um teste de compatibilidade (Plugins -> Jetpack Compatibility Test).